# how to make brunch copy image files into public/images

Tags: brunch

I installed jquery-ui using npm. How can I copy `node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/.../images/*.png` to `public/images` directory in Brunch build? I do not want to manually copy files under `assets/`

Answer (score 0):

[`after-brunch`](https://github.com/Creative-Licence-Digital/after-brunch) plug-in does the trick. You can execute arbitrary cmd commands after the build using this plug-in. Many thanks to Creative-Licence-Digital...

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from `node_modules` to `app/assets`.